# (Co)kernels commute with direct sums (and limits)?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, limits-colimits

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $(\varphi_i: (M_i \to N_i))_{i \in I}$ a
family of $R$-module morphisms. Take

$$\varphi= \bigoplus \varphi: \bigoplus_i M_i \to \bigoplus_i N_i$$

Questions:

Does the cokernel $coker(\varphi)$ commute with direct sum?
That is do we have always
$coker(\bigoplus_i \varphi)= \bigoplus_i coker(\varphi_i)$?

If we now deal instead of direct sums more generally with direct
limits and maps

$$\phi := \varinjlim_i  \phi_i: \varinjlim_i M_i \to \varinjlim_i N_i $$

between direct limits of direct systems
$(M_i)_i$ and $(N_i)_i$ and compatible maps $\phi: M_i \to N_i$, does
cokernel also commute with direct limit? That is do we have
$coker(\varinjlim_i \phi)= \varinjlim_i coker(\phi_i)$.

Is the same true if we deal now with kernel instead of
cokernel?

I think the first two questions should be true and can be proved
by universal property of direct sum: for any $R$-module $A$ a morphism
$f:\bigoplus_i N_i \to A$ factorize over
$coker(\bigoplus_i \varphi)$ iff $f \circ \varphi $ is zero.
But $f \circ \varphi $ is zero iff for all $i$ the compositions
$f \circ \varphi_i $ are zeoes iff for all $i$ $f$ factorize
over $coker(\varphi_i)$.

Universal property of direct sum says that a morphism
$\bigoplus_i coker(\varphi_i) \to A$ is the same as
a family of morphisms $coker(\varphi_i) \to A$, and
therefore $\bigoplus_i coker(\varphi_i)$ and $coker(\varphi)$
share same universal property.

Is my argument fine? Is there a another more simple one known?
If it wirks then it should be not hart the extend it to
direct limit uning now the universal property of directs
limits instead, okay?

What about the case if we talk about kernel of $\varphi$ instead of
cokernel?

Comment: Left adjoints respect colimits, right adjoints respect limits. The direct sum is coproduct, which is the left adjoint of the diagonal functor, so direct sums respect colimits, including the cokernel.

Comment: Likewise, if your category is cocomplete so that all direct limits exist (as is the case here), then the direct limit construction is the right adjoint of diagonal/constant functor, so direct limits respect colimits, hence the cokernel.

Comment: I'm slightly perplexed about your argument that 
'direct sum is the left adjoint to diagonal functor'. 
Yes, there is a rule that a functor $F$ respects colimits if
there exist another functor with $hom(F(-),-)=hom(-,G(-))$, 
that's your left adjointness rule. But:
the direct sum is at all not a functor but an object in $R$-mod,
so I not understand how you regard it as a 'functor'. Could you 
clarify it shortly?

Comment: The direct sum over index $J$ is a functor from the $J$-fold product of the category $R$-$\mathbf{Mod}$ to $R$-$\mathbf{Mod}$, taking a $J$-tuple $(M_j)$ to its direct sum. It is the adjoint of the “diagonal functor” from $R$-$\mathbf{Mod}$ to the $J$-fold product that takes a module $M$ and sends it to the “constant tuple” $(M)_{j\in J}$.

Comment: This argument actually generalizes to arbitrary limits and colimits: if all functors from $\mathbf{D}$ to $\mathbf{C}$ have (co)limits, then the (co)limit construction gives a functor from the functor category $\mathbf{C}^{\mathbf{D}}$ to $\mathbf{C}$, taking each functor $F\colon\mathbf{D}\to\mathbf{C}$ to its (co)limit. The “diagonal functor” going the other way takes an object $X$ of $\mathbf{C}$ and maps it to the constant functor $\Delta_X\colon\mathbf{D}\to\mathbf{C}$, taking every object to $X$ and every morphism to $\mathrm{id}_X$. (cont)

Comment: It is then a fairly straightfoward to verify that the (co)limit construction, viewed as functors, are adjoints to the diagonal functor on either side.

Comment: As far as the kernel, I believe that it just happens to work out in Modules, but that this is happenstance rather than a consequence of general category-theory arguments. The direct limit is exact for modules, after all.

Comment: thank you, everything is clear now. +1

Comment: ...except one $D$etail: your $D$ is the category of diagrams?

Comment: In that comment, $\mathbf{D}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ are just arbitrary categories. For the direct limit over index $I$, you can take the category $I_{\mathbf{cat}}$ whose objects are the elements of $I$ and where there exists a unique arrow from $i$ to $j$ if and only if $i\leq j$. A functor from $I_{\mathbf{cat}}$ to $\mathbf{C}$ is a directed system in $\mathbf{C}$. (You can do the same thing for products indexed over a set $J$ by taking $J_{\mathbf{cat}}$ to be the category whose objects are the elements of $J$ and whose only morphisms are the identity maps)